# Random deallocation of UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am having a heck of a time debugging an iOS app crash issue. I have a `UIViewController` where I define its `UIView` in `loadView`. I also retain a copy of the `UIView` so that I can send messages to it such as (the view has been rotated) things of that nature. In addition to this the `UIView` has its own delegate member (uses assign, does not retain the ref to parent) that contains an association to the parent. (This is a pattern used in one of the Apple docs - I'm wondering if this isn't part of my issue as there is a circular reference between the two objects)

Here is the hierarchical view of the objects:

`UIViewController`
+ `UIView`
  + `NSNotificationCenter UIKeyboardDidShow`

The issue occurs when the `NSNotification` for `UIKeyboardDidShow` fires and the parent delegate method gets called. I know that the delegate was *set*. However, somehow, somewhere the delegate is getting released. Also, the `_bufferViewDelegate` gets set *only* once. Lastly, this doesn't happen every time. It happens rarely.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x325f288f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34648259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x325f5a9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
3   CoreFoundation                  0x325f4915 ___forwarding___ + 301
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3254f650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   Buffer                          0x0008716d -[BufferView scrollToCursor] (BufferView.m:4348)
6   Buffer                          0x00080407 -[BufferView keyboardDidShow:] (BufferView.m:1379)
7   Foundation                      0x37f3d4ff __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 19
8   CoreFoundation                  0x325be547 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 71
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3254a097 _CFXNotificationPost + 1407
10  Foundation                      0x37eb13eb -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 67
11  UIKit                           0x3209f029 -[UIInputViewTransition postNotificationsForTransitionEnd] + 789
12  UIKit                           0x3233a51f __53-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:]_block_invoke_01008 + 159
13  UIKit                           0x320344db -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 215
14  UIKit                           0x3202eaab -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 471
15  UIKit                           0x320343d5 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 53
16  QuartzCore                      0x342dbc2f CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 203
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x35c4ae91 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 197
18  CoreFoundation                  0x325c52ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1269
19  CoreFoundation                  0x325484a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3254836d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
21  GraphicsServices                0x3169f439 GSEventRunModal + 137
22  UIKit                           0x32047cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
23  Buffer                          0x0005c20b main (main.m:20)
24  Buffer                          0x0005bcac start + 40
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Resolved the issue. What I did was put NSLog statements in both the controller and all subviews to determine if everything was getting released as I expected. It wasn't. What I expected, and occurred most of the time, was this:

```
UIViewController loadView <-- Open the view, init the BufferView
UIViewController dealloc
BufferView dealloc
```

What was happening was that sometimes the BufferView never had its dealloc method called!

The code in the UIViewController looked something like this:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    ...

    // bufferView is a member var of this particular UIViewController
    bufferView = [[BufferView alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:view];

    ...
}
```

When the UIViewController dealloc method was called I would release the bufferView.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    ...

    [bufferView release];
    bufferView = nil;

    ...

    [super dealloc];
}
```

When I changed the code to this in the loadView:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    ...

    // bufferView is a member var of this particular UIViewController
    bufferView = [[BufferView alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:view];
    [bufferView release];

    ...
}
```

and removed the release command in dealloc everything started working as I expected. It seems like best practice is to release the view after adding it to the subview. I've seen this pattern in other applications but never understood why it had to be this way. Hope this helps someone else out.

Please note that I haven't experienced a crash in over a day. This is way better than it was before. I'll update the ticket if this turns out to be the wrong solution.

**UPDATE 3**

The above did not work. I am now registering/unregistering the notifications in the UIViewController viewWillAppear, viewDidDisappear methods. Problem solved. So far as I can tell everyone's suggestion is to put the [[NSNotification defaultCenter] removeObserver:self] call in dealloc. This is not a good idea at all. You **can not** rely on the system to dealloc your object in the time frame you are expecting it to occur. Maybe in some cases it will work just fine, but not in all. I suggest that you try to register/unregister the calls only when you need them. In my case I only need them when the view is being displayed and unregistering when the view is not being displayed. Crash free for a day (we'll see how long that lasts). I'll update in a few days with my success.

**UPDATE 4**

That was the issue. No more crashes. So make sure you are registering your observers only when you absolutely need them and unregister them when you don't.

Comment: Note that by the time that crash occurs the damage is long done.  Once the object's been deallocated it's a ticking time bomb.

Comment: (Who is retaining your UIViewController?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out when an object is dealloced, placed an NSLog in it's `dealloc` routine.  And placing an address stop in the `dealloc` will allow you to display the call stack and see who is doing the `release` that frees the object.

I suspect what you have is that the object is actually getting dealloced even sooner than you think, but during the timer event the storage is recycled, and that's when the error is detected.

Comment: It only ever gets dealloc'ed at the time the UIViewController gets popped off of the navigation stack. What I've done for now is remove the NSTimer. Since then, I haven't gotten a crash yet. I'd like to think this is the solution to the answer but I put that NSTimer in there as it was crashing before as well. Then again, there have been several modifications to this class since I put the NSTimer logic in there. So it's possible that with the latest changes it may "work".

Comment: @echamber -- You THINK that's when it gets dealloced, and you THINK that the timer never goes off after it's been dealloced.  Obviously, one of those two presumptions is wrong.

Comment: That's what I've observed. When I click the left arrow to go to the previous view the dealloc call gets made. I just wanted to point out that even with the fix I described above it still crashes. I updated the main question with the new stack trace.

Comment: This will only tell you who was last to release the object. A better solution is to either set `NSZombieEnabled` (to find out who is trying to access the object without retaining it) or the Allocations instrument in `Instruments.app`, which will give you the entire retain-release life of the object.

Comment: Is it possible that iOS is killing my app because I'm using too much memory? That seems like the only logical explanation for this. I've read a few articles related to how iOS manages memory and it's possible that they may just kill an app if the app isn't heading memory warnings (which it is)... and may decide to kill it altogether if it believes the app isn't behaving? I'm going to do a little research to see if this is a possibility.

Comment: Nope.  You'd have different symptoms if it were a memory issue.  You're just doing something "stupid" with regard to memory management.  It happens to all of us.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I am definitely doing something stupid. I finally replicated the issue. The issue occurs only when I run several applications in the background, come back to the app, and then tap to enter editing mode. Here's a nice snippet of the exception: 2012-05-17 22:49:25.493 Buffer[3081:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI bufferViewStoppedScrolling]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2c46b0'. Well now that's weird! It's sending the message to an __NSArrayI object! I'll respond back when I know more.

Comment: I forgot to add that the object isn't being dealloc'ed. I put many NSLog statements in the locations where the UIViewController and all UIViews are alloc'ed / dealloc'ed. None of the NSLog messages get called during the time the exception occurred. So there is definitely some weird memory management issue going on.

Comment: @echamber -- Did you put NSLogs in your `dealloc` routines??  My suspicion is that your view controller is getting dealloced (because it's not properly retained) and that's taking everything with it.  Note that the "unrecognized selector" occurs because the object implementing "bufferViewStoppedScrolling" got deallocated and a string was allocated in its place -- a classical sign of a deallocated object.  (Like I said above, once the object's deallocated it's a time bomb (or maybe better, a "booby trap") waiting for later code to touch it, so where the actual error occurs is no big help.)

Comment: That's what I've observed in the past as well (where an object gets dealloc'ed and a pointer to another object takes its place). Trying to track down where exactly the UIViewController is getting dealloc'ed. And yes, I did end up putting NSLog statements in the dealloc method. The strange thing is that that at the time the exception occurred the NSLog statement wasn't called. So I don't know if it was dealloc'ed in another thread that didn't print out the NSLog before the app crashed or what. I'll have to get to this later tonight. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can always put a breakpoint in the dealloc method.  Also consider the possibility that the object containing the pointer you're referencing has been reallocated.

Comment: Discovered the issue. The UIViewController _was_ being dealloc'ed but not in the way I expected. The process was: the view loaded, the view unloaded and dealloc'ed both the controller and view. In some rare instances the _view_ did **not** get dealloc'ed. The issue was that at the time I created the view object I didn't send a release... however, I _did_ send a release in the controller's dealloc method. The fix was to release the view directly after adding it to the subview and removing the dealloc call within dealloc. Such a weird issue as I _was_ balancing the retain/release calls.